# Adjusting order of stacked bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have not been able to figure this out and have not found a similar question. I would like to show a bar chart where the Y axis is "subject" and then for each subject there is a stacked bar showing the order in which medications were given.

```
[Subject, Mednum, Medname]
Subj A  Med0    MednameX
Subj B  Med0    MednameY
Subj B  Med1    MednameX
Subj B  Med2    MednameZ
Subj C  Med0    MednameP
Subj C  Med1    MednameX
```

If I use this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Subject, y=Mednum,fill=Medname)) + geom_col() + coord_flip()
```

I get:

[image]

Not only do I want each stacked bar to be the same height (I can add another column to dataset with values 1 so that everything is size 1), but the ordering is incorrect - as you can see for Subject B, the stacked bars (ordered by Mednum) should be MednameY --> MednameX --> MednameZ.

Anyone have a solution? Essentially I want to order the stacked bars NOT by the fill labels, but by an additional (fourth) variable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what your are looking for. If I got you right you could achieve your desired result by switching to `geom_tile`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(y = Subject, x = Mednum, fill = Medname)) +
  geom_tile()
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
data <- structure(list(Subject = c(
  "Subj A", "Subj B", "Subj B", "Subj B",
  "Subj C", "Subj C"
), Mednum = c(
  "Med0", "Med0", "Med1", "Med2",
  "Med0", "Med1"
), Medname = c(
  "MednameX", "MednameY", "MednameX",
  "MednameZ", "MednameP", "MednameX"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```